# Can't get Facebook login to work with AngularFire 0.5

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

So I'm trying to use Facebook login with angularfire 0.5 and I'm having some issues.
I've simply copy-pasted the documentation code from the angularfire website but it doesn't seem to trigger a connection to Facebook.

This is my controller code:

```
     .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $firebase, $firebaseAuth) {
    var ref = new Firebase('https://xlib.firebaseio.com/lunsjfeed');
    $scope.auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);

  });
```

This is the code from the view:

```
<a href="#" ng-hide="auth.user" ng-click="auth.$login('facebook')">Login</a>
```

I get no errors in the console. I can fetch and write data to firebase without any problems, but I can't the login api to work.

Comment: You included https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase-simple-login.js script?

Comment: What output do you get if you try `$scope.$on` against the `$firebaseAuth:login`, `$firebaseAuth:logout`, and `$firebaseAuth:error` events? Have you verified that facebook authentication is enabled in Forge?

Comment: My bad! I forgot to include the firebase-simple-login.js. Thanks a lot :)